# gwt-dev as maven dependency issue

Tags: maven, gwt, intellij-idea

Though i haven't any experience with gwt, my current task is integrating existing gwt project with maven. Some of the project java classes extend from com.google.gwt.core.ext.generator which is part of gwt-dev.jar. My issue is that gwt-dev.jar is not recommended to be included as maven dependency(even with provided scope), but in that case my project can't be compiled. How such kind of problem can be resolved ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the warning printed by Mojo's Maven Plugin for GWT, you can ignore it. If it ever causes issues, it'd mean you don't have split your client and server code in separate modules. gwt-dev as a dependency is the *recommended* setup, Mojo's Maven Plugin for GWT just hasn't updated yet.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Sorry for missing upvote, i have not enough reputation yet for upvoting.